# I want to develop a quiz game based application in Android

Tags: android

I want the list of free APIs available for quiz game based on location in Android. I searched many sources, but I couldn't get any. I found only one API. Can anyone please give me the list of free quiz APIs. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a couple of API for this purpose:

Trivia: 
https://opentdb.com/api_config.php
https://jservice.io/

Words:
https://www.twinword.com/api/word-quiz.php

Technical topics:
https://quizapi.io/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

opentdb.com provides nice json api. You need to configure it in the page and generate the api you need